# How do i change the default shell for shell-command

Tags: shell, shell-command, default

I am having an issue with one of the plugins i am running because its trying to use fish and does not like the parameters.

Is there a way i can change emacs to use bash for any plugins that use shell-command or similar functions.

```
(setenv "SHELL" "/bin/bash")
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")
```

I tried the above but shell-command still seems to use fish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change the option `shell-file-name`.

---

> (setenv "SHELL" "/bin/bash")

This doesn't work since Emacs is already running thus it's too late, Emacs initializes `shell-file-name` according to  `SHELL` during startup. Something like

```
$ SHELL=/bin/bash emacs
```

should work.

> (setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")

This is for `M-x shell`, not `M-x shell-command`.

Comment: Cheers, I can work with that i was hoping there might have been a nicer solution I will wait in case anyone else knows another way, else i will accept this answer.

Comment: @Oly Don't know about your expect. Setting `shell-file-name` to bash is sufficient for you, I think.

Comment: Cheers the correct answer is (setq shell-file-name "/bin/bash") this makes shell-command use bash instead of the default, and has fixed the plugin i am trying to use :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

`(setenv "ESHELL" "/bin/bash")`

Here's an excerpt from the implementation of `shell`.

```
...
   ;; Rain or shine, BUFFER must be current by now.
   (unless (comint-check-proc buffer)
     (let* ((prog (or explicit-shell-file-name
                      (getenv "ESHELL") shell-file-name))
            (name (file-name-nondirectory prog))
...
```

Here's a link to it in the emacs mirror on github

https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/a1abb6a85e6605c256595b8d7b885018e5421c28/lisp/shell.el#L927