# Switch Emacs default shell from bash to zsh or fish

Tags: term

When I deleted the zsh shell to move to fish, alot of my emacs configuration got messed up. It won't recognize my racer (Rust autocomplete) or do syntax highlighting. When I run doom reload, it gives me an error saying the zsh is no longer there. How can I switch from zsh to fish in emacs?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28647/how-do-i-change-the-default-shell-for-shell-command and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409085/how-to-define-a-default-shell-for-emacs/37523213

Comment: Yes, the first one did, thank you.